# Lowercase font in title for book

Tags: fonts, books

I need to change the title of a section of my thesis (`book`), so that it shows nDCT instead of [image]

What is the best way to do it? I tried using both `\texorpdfstring{\MakeLowercase{n}DCT}{nDCT}` and `\MakeLowercase{n}DCT` but none worked.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[openany,english,a4paper,12pt,twoside,titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage{sectsty}

\partnumberfont{\fontfamily{ppl}\mdseries\scshape\Large}
\parttitlefont{\fontfamily{ppl}\mdseries\scshape\LARGE}
\chapternumberfont{\sffamily\mdseries\scshape\LARGE}
\chaptertitlefont{\fontfamily{ppl}\mdseries\upshape\Huge}
\sectionfont{\fontfamily{ppl}\bfseries\scshape\Large}
\subsectionfont{\fontfamily{ppl}\bfseries\scshape\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is everything uppercased in the first place? Please show us a minimal working example.

Comment: I just added it in the question

Comment: It is not uppercase, it is in small caps, as you declared; do `\texorpdfstring{\textnormal{n}DCT}{nDCT}`

Comment: That works wonderfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `\scshape` and so the `n` is typeset in the small caps font.

For this particular case, do

```
\textnormal{nDCT}
```

or, maybe,

```
\texorpdfstring{\textnormal{nDCT}}{nDCT}
```

and you'll be OK.